# Finding the radius of convergence of $\frac{z+1}{z^2+z+1}$ about $z=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

So the problem asks to find the radius of convergence without finding the power series itself. I thought it would be best to begin by factoring the denominator. That can by done by the quadratic formula and we obtain that:

$z = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$. If we want the radius of convergence about $z=3$ can we just say since $z = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ then $z-3 = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2} -3 = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i-6}{2}$. But from here where do I need to take this? if this is the right track to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularities are at:  $z=(-1\pm\sqrt3i)/2$.  You could note that the nearest singularity to $z=3$ is at a distance $d=\sqrt{(49+3)/4}=\sqrt{52/4}=\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: It would also be $z= \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ right? not just 3 in the numerator?

Comment: Oh yeah.  I will need to correct.

Comment: wouldn't the distance be defined as $d= \sqrt{(\frac{-1}{2} - 3)^2 + \frac{3}{4}}$ or am I seeing that wrong?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake.